# Unwanted top padding inside div element

Tags: html, padding, css

I have such HTML:

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select name="type">
        <option value="test">test</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And css:

```
#search-box .select-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px;
    background: #eaeced;
}

#search-box select {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -border-radius:2px;
}
```

However somehow wrappers top padding is bigger then bottom one:

[image: ss1]

When I highlight wrapper in inspector, it looks like that:

[image: ss2]

As you can see, there is some space between selects top border and top of the inner content of a wrapping div.

Why is it there ? How can I force both top and bottom spacing to be equal ? I need that wrapping element for additional outer border.

CSS outline and box-shadow isn't enough, because I need to specify corner rounding. Shadows rounding is relative to border rounding and its too big for me, so I need to make this outer border with DIV-wrapper with my own, small border-radius.

Comment: Your markup and style is not related to. Could you show us some [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You're only missing the parent element (`#search-box`)... the styles do relate to the rest (with a little bit of imagination :) )

Comment: The code given does not demonstrate the issue pictured. You should check the code before posting it to make sure it illustrates the problem. Either that or specify the browser in which it's observed ... because none of mine present the select the way you picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the `select` is smaller than the inner height of `.select-wrapper`.

Add `display: block` and `height: 100%` to the select so it will take the full height and width of it's parent.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/fszuho0q/).

Answer (score 0):

You could change the font size to 100%, although it changes the font size from what you originally coded, it does sort the padding outside of the select box.

```
#search-box select { font-size:100%; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r2wpxvw2/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sj1aL1o8/

```
.select-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px;
    background: #eaeced;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```